# Adding a null terminator to a string

Tags: c

I have used sscanf to scan in a string and add it to a structure. The only problem is that I cannot print out the string because there is no null terminator added by default. I tried to add a null in there with the strcat() function but came to the realization this cannot work. Thanks for any help.

```
struct a
{
int *ref;
char string[50];
}rec;

void task()
{


   char *p_test;

   char test[50] = "9999:STRING OF TEXT";
   p_test = test;

   sscanf(p_test, "%d:%[^\n]", &rec.ref, rec.string);

   printf("String is:%s", &rec.string);

}
```

Comment: Do correct the syntax errors buddy.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I am still getting the syntax errors: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'sscanf' [enabled by default]| and incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default] and im not sure why. How am I using these functions wrong?

Comment: You must include the header files that define the library functions you use ... in this case you need `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

1. ```
   test[50] = "9999:STRING OF TEXT";
   ```

This is wrong for two reasons.

A) `test` is an array of `char`, not an array of `char*`.  So, when you assign a string (a `char*`) to an element, the address is converted to a `char`.

B) Element `50` does not exist in your array, and writing to it invokes undefined behavior.  You have an array of `50` elements with indices `0...49`.

To assign an initial value to your array, all you need do is:

```
char test[50] = "9999:STRING OF TEXT";
```

And since `test` does not need to be modified...

```
const char *test = "9999:STRING OF TEXT";
```

2. If you want to zero an array, the simplest method is:

   ```
   char test[50] = {0};
   ```

Of course, you don't need to if you assign the string properly to begin with, and this is not your problem.

3. Your `string` member of the `a` struct is a `char`, not a `char*` (a string), and using the `%s` format specifier when printing it invokes undefined behavior.
4. `main` is defined to return `int`, not `void`.
5. `sscanf` expects pointers to data to fill in.  `rec.ref` is an `int`, you need to pass its address, i.e., `&rec.ref`.
6. You need to allocate storage for `rec.string`.

---

Here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING_LEN 50

struct a
{
    int ref;
    char string[STRING_LEN];
} rec;

int main()
{
    char test[STRING_LEN] = "9999:STRING OF TEXT";

    // note that, in the real world, this may 
    // be a buffer overflow waiting to happen
    sscanf(test, "%d:%[^\n]", &rec.ref, rec.string);

    printf("String is:%s, rec is:%d", rec.string, rec.ref);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems; a lack of null-terminator actually isn't one of them.

One problem is a syntax error; this:

```
   char test[50]
   test[50] = "9999:STRING OF TEXT";
```

is not valid syntax. You need:

```
   char test[50] = "9999:STRING OF TEXT";
```

Another problem is that `rec` doesn't have a string (a `char *` or `char[]`), it just has a single character (a `char`). A simple approach, to get you started, is:

```
struct a
{
    int ref;
    char string[50];
} rec;
```

A third problem is that `sscanf`'s arguments all have to be pointers. C is a pass-by-value language; if you just pass in an integer, that doesn't give `sscanf` any way to modify that integer:

```
sscanf(test, "%d:%[\n]", &rec.ref, rec.string); // (once rec.string is a pointer)
```

A fourth problem is that the format-specifier `%[\n]` does not mean what you seem to want it to mean. (Maybe you actually wanted `%[^\n]`?)

Other, smaller issues include your return-type for `main` (it should be `int`, not `void`).

The common thread with most of these issues is that your compiler would have eagerly helped you identify them, had you simply turned on compiler warnings!